# SNMP is it possible to monitor shared printers?

Tags: snmp, network-printer, print-server, shared-printers

I have a folowing Network scheme:

[image]

Server has PrintServer role enabled and printers is shared. I want to monitor printers state/errors through SNMP from any user PC but problem is that I haven't acess to any printer directly through IP address because it is in a different network. I can operate with printer ONLY as a shared i.e. through printserver, so my question is - how I can make SNMP requests to shared printer? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install nrpe server on your server and send snmp requests from your server to yours printers. Nrpd will receive the response of yours printers and send it to your supervisor.

Comment: thanks for response, could you provide some links please?